# Davies-Meyer mode

Tags: encryption, hash

While reading about the [Davies-Meyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function#Davies%E2%80%93Meyer) mode (and other modes), I have got some doubts:

1. What can I use as the key to the encryption $E$? Since I am generating hash of a message (not MAC), then there should not be any secret key involved.
2. What is the initial hash value ($H_0$)? Can I take it as some public value (IV/nonce) so that it can be changed, or I can set it to be a randomly chosen constant? [Related question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/31608/16588)
3. (To the previous questions) Can the message $M$ is chosen as the key to $E$? Can $M$ be chosen as $H_0$? Can $M$ be chosen as the key to $E$ and as $H_0$?
4. Say, I want to use AES as $E$ (which gives 128-bit output), then it is true the Davies-Meyer output is compulsorily of 128 bits?

Comment: Davies-Meyer mode is not an encryption mode. It is used for building one-way compression functions ( hash). Bases on this knowledge it is better to re-write your question. 2) $H_0$ can be a nothing in my sleeve number. 3) It is better to be fixed. 4) yes.

Comment: @kelalaka ... but this modes requires an encryption. First question is about the encryption function that is used inside this mode.

Comment: This mode uses a block cipher to build compression functions as in SHA-2 series. We don't consider it encryption. As you can see, the message is used as a key.

Comment: @kelalaka OK... Then my question is, what is used as the *plaintext* input of the block cipher?

Comment: While buildinh the hash functions on MD construction like SHA-2 it is the message itself, and $H_0$ is the fixed initial value.