# Why is the compression function in Miyaguchi-Preneel scheme secure?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, miyaguchi-preneel

I was reading about the Miyaguchi-Preneel scheme and had difficulty in understanding why the compression function, $h(H,m)=E(H, H \oplus M) \oplus M \oplus H$ can be called secure. The only resource I could find about this was [Black-Box Analysis of the Block-Cipher-Based Hash-Function Constructions from PGV](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/hash.pdf).

Again, I am having trouble with the explanation provided there. So, if someone could please clear my doubt, that would be great, thanks!

Comment: Did you read [this answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/8024/13625)? It points to that paper so perhaps you did?

Comment: Thanks, I did. I looked at this first, before posting my question. The one who answered there has only referred to that paper and explained what an ideal cipher is. I already know the latter, it is the explanation in the paper/the answer to my question, that I want help with.

Comment: The formula you have given seems to be incorrect to me.